# What does the csv.writerow() method return?

Tags: python, csv

I am learning how to write to a `CSV` file using the built-in csv module.

I open the file using the below code:

```
file_to_output=open('to_save_file.csv', mode='w', newline='')
```

Then I create a csv writer object:

```
csv_writer = csv.writer(file_to_output, delimiter=',')
```

Then I write a row using `writerow`:

```
csv_writer.writerow(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Now, this function returns `7`.

Many posts say that this number is the number of characters written, but when I close and check the file, only `5` characters are written to the file, i.e., `a,b,c`.

What does this number signify?

Comment: I guess you are running your test on a Windows machine. The extra two characters are the line termination indicator, which is `\r\n` _CRLF_ on Windows, so `writerow()` is indeed returning the number of bytes written.

Comment: Just checked and even on Linux, the `csv` module uses _`CRLF`_ as the line termination inidcator.

Comment: I am using MAC OS

Comment: Either way,  the default `dialect` for `csv.writer` is `excel`, which uses _`CRLF`_ as the line termination indicator. You can play around and pass `dialect='unix'`, and then `writerow` will return `6` instead because in Unix-like systems the line termination indicator is just _`LF`_, accounting for one extra character.

Answer (score 2):

Just going off the docs:

[`csvwriter.writerow(row)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerow):

> ... Return the return value of the call to the write method of the underlying file object.

[`TextIOBase.write(s)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=iobase#io.TextIOBase.write):

> ... return the number of characters written.

So the answer to the question is technically whatever the underlying write method returns, which in your example (a TextIOBase file) is the number of *characters* written.

But, pragmatically, @accdias is right, you're seeing the effect of the default dialect using CRLF.  I'm using a Mac, too, 12.1:

```py
import csv

writer = csv.writer(open('output.csv', 'w', newline=''))
writer.writerow(['a','b','c'])
```

```
% hexdump -C output.csv
00000000  61 2c 62 2c 63 0d 0a                              |a,b,c..|
00000007
```

From [the csv module source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/csv.py#L54):

```py
class excel(Dialect):
    """Describe the usual properties of Excel-generated CSV files."""
    delimiter = ','
    quotechar = '"'
    doublequote = True
    skipinitialspace = False
    lineterminator = '\r\n'
    quoting = QUOTE_MINIMAL
```

You can change `dialect=` or `lineterminator=` when you instantiate `writer()`:

```py
writer = csv.writer(open('output.csv', 'w', newline=''), lineterminator='\n')
```

and now I get:

```
00000000  61 2c 62 2c 63 0a                                 |a,b,c.|
00000006
```

Comment: As the `csv` module's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) menions, the closest thing to a standard for the CSV file format is [RFC 4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180.html), which specifies that lines are delimited by CRLF (whether on a Mac or not). That's why default is to do that. I think major applications like MS Excel do it that way, too.